# connect phone to Android-Studio in Ubuntu for debugging

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, usb

I'm new on Ubuntu and install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and for framework I download non-installable Android Studio and SDK tools separately.

I tried [this link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2154543) for Installing USB device on Ubuntu. I succeed in installing USB as MTP. but it wont load in Android Studio. when I run my app "waiting for adb" dialog is shown and finnaly says ADB not responding.

first I thought this is because I don't install adb so I install it with command:

```
sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb
```

but still phone wont load for launch app. is this ADB issue or cause my Android Studio is wont installed or some thing else.

Comment: Your phone driver is not proper install in Ubuntu 14.04 so you can select the option mtp in the usb debugging from phone then it easily connect with the Ubuntu and also you can see your phone in adb.

Comment: @RikzPatel I changed to mtp  but nothing shown. as I say I don't install ADB manually. is it Run with Android studio or I should Install it by myself?

Comment: when I Run my app I't's wait for ADB forever and then tell me "restart ADB"

Comment: @RikzPatel I updated the question plz check

Answer (score 3):

in **Ubuntu** you have to create a rules file called *51-android.rules.*

here is the details link: [Unable to use my Android device as Android emulator using Android studio](https://askubuntu.com/questions/599086/unable-to-use-my-android-device-as-android-emulator-using-android-studio)

here is the gitHub links: [51-android](https://github.com/snowdream/51-android) or 
[51-android.rules](https://github.com/M0Rf30/android-udev-rules/blob/master/51-android.rules)

Answer (score 1):

*if you have tried many terminal commands to connect your physical device to android studio in ubuntu and you failed to connect try this :-*
Connect your device and change your USB preference(device notification) to **PTP**,android studio will detect your device.

Comment: I didn't try any of the terminal commands and just tried this and it worked!